# Запомнить привязанные свойства для CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Код ниже выполняет привязку строк из `CheckedListBox1`-а к свойствам `Value`, которые в свою очередь связаны с `TextBox`-ами. Подскажите пожалуйста, как в **C# WinForms VS2010** исправить следующую проблему: значения `Value` запоминаются только если строка из `CheckedListBox1`-а принимает статус `Unchecked`.Например, после привязки, для каждой строки из `CheckedListBox1` вводятся значения в `TextBox`-ы, и эти значения запоминаются только если строки попереключать, другими словами, если вводить данные в `TextBox`-ы с текущим статусом строки `Checked` для `CheckedListBox1`-а, то они не запоминаются?

```
public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value1 { get; set; }
        public string Value2 { get; set; }
        public string Value3 { get; set; }
    }

private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  people = new BindingList<Person>();
  foreach (var item in CheckedListBox1.Items)
    {
       Person p = new Person
       {
                Name = item.ToString(),
                Value1 = TextBox1.Text,
                Value2 = TextBox2.Text,
                Value3 = TextBox3.Text,
       };
       people.Add(p);
    }

   var listBox = ((ListBox)CheckedListBox1);
   listBox.DataSource = people;
   listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";

   TextBox1.DataBindings.Clear();
   TextBox2.DataBindings.Clear();
   TextBox3.DataBindings.Clear();

   TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", people, "Value1");
   TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", people, "Value2");
   TextBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", people, "Value3");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перепишите привязка таким образом

```
TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", people, "Value1",DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Если вы не укажете `OnPropertyChanged`,объект модели не будет обновляться,читайте [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1618543/7198805)